# In R: is there a way to render a graph for two groups of nodes with different lengths?

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer

I'd like to generate a graph from two different sets of nodes which they have different lengths. You can find the codes below.

As you can see I receive an error : Error: length(from) == length(to) is not TRUE
!!
Is there a solution to this one?

I'd appreciate your help !!

```
library(DiagrammeR)
g1<- c("a","b","c")
g2<-c("d","f")

#creating a node data frame
nodes1<- create_node_df(n=length(g1),
                   style= "filled",
                   color= "lightblue",
                   shape= "box")

nodes2<- create_node_df(n=length(g2),
                    style= "filled",
                    color= "lightblue",
                    shape= "box")
edges<-create_edge_df(from = g1,
                  to= g2,
                  rel= "related",
                  color= "black")

Error: length(from) == length(to) is not TRUE



all_nodes<- combine_ndfs(nodes1, nodes2)

create_graph(nodes_df = all_nodes,
                                    edges_df = edges,
                                    directed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you mean connecting each vertex of `g1` with each of `g2`. After defining `nodes1` and `nodes2`, let

```
(all_nodes <- combine_ndfs(nodes1, nodes2))
#   id type label  style     color shape
# 1  1 <NA>  <NA> filled lightblue   box
# 2  2 <NA>  <NA> filled lightblue   box
# 3  3 <NA>  <NA> filled lightblue   box
# 4  4 <NA>  <NA> filled lightblue   box
# 5  5 <NA>  <NA> filled lightblue   box
```

Since later we are going to use this variable in `create_graph`, we want to connect each of 1, 2, 3 with each of 4 and 5. To construct proper arguments for `create_edge_df` we are going to use `rep`; that is because, as `?create_edge_df` says,

> from - a vector of node ID values from which edges are outbound. **The
>   vector length must equal that of the to vector.**
>
> to - a vector of node ID values to which edges are incoming. **The vector length must equal that of the from vector.**

So,

```
edges <- create_edge_df(from = rep(1:3, 2), to = rep(4:5, each = 3),
                        rel = "related", color = "black")
create_graph(nodes_df = all_nodes, edges_df = edges, directed = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Zero, did that help?

Comment: I have a follow-up question to this. I have tried your solution but it generates arbitrary connections among nodes (which is normal because I didn't add it). Anyway, do you know how we can derive such a graph with your solution??  I added the image in the question

Comment: @Zero, first, you should erase that graph from the question as it's unrelated to the original question. Second, your original question and my answer are not really suitable for that graph. They are suitable when there is some sort of bipartiteness in the graph, with two clear groups of vertices. You have a simple graph and should simply enumerate all the edges. Namely, use `edges <- create_edge_df(from = c("a", "a", "a", ...), to = c("a", "b", "d", ...), ...)` and so on. Or perhaps 1 instead of "a", 2 instead of "b", etc.